# Determining the standard deviation based on standard deviations from 2 data sets (paired)

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation, meta-analysis

I would like to run an analysis on the effectiveness of a drug on a specific parameter. In 1 study, mean and SD values were reported at baseline, and post-treatment for both experimental and control groups.

For my analysis, I would like to determine if the drug can result in a change in the parameter values. So, I will be taking: baseline value - post-treatment value

However, I am not sure how, or if it is possible, to determine the SD values for the change in parameter values.

Any help/advice will be greatly appreciated!

Example:

Aim: To determine the effectiveness of a supplement for weight loss

Results reported:

Baseline and Post-intervention weight of participants(mean and SD) in intervention and placebo group.

How I would like to extrapolate the data:

Mean weight change: baseline weight- post-intervention weight

SD: area that require advice!

Comment: Well, either Mann-Whitney U tests(A.k.A. Wilcoxon Rank Sum test) & Kruskal-Wallis H [Tests](https://www.reed.edu/psychology/stata/analyses/nonparametric/kruskal-wallacetheory.html) depending on what you are doing.

Comment: You would need the correlation between per and post to estimate the variance of the change score.